# Root an LG Spirit with no closed source programs

Tags: rooting, lg, open-source

I own an LG Spirit (Android 6.0) and I'm sick of the limitations that are put on my phone. I decided to attempt rooting, and possibly bootloader unlocking and flashing. But, for now, I'm stuck on rooting.

My problem is that I want to totally avoid execution of closed source software that requires and/or manages root access. I'm not a developer, but I put far more trust in open source software that I can read (even if I lack the skills, but it's a nice moment to learn something new) than in shady¹ applications that promise me to root a phone with one click. I'd like to learn something about the process that I'm doing on my phone, and I never trusted the easy ways when dealing with electronic devices.

Fact is, I don't know where to begin. I've found phh's project, superuser (git: https://github.com/phhusson/Superuser), but the documentation is so technical I really can't understand a thing, even if my phone is supported (or if I can create the necessary files, or else). When I look for newbie guides to rooting, all I can find are guides to the one click root apps (that can be summarized as "Download->Click Root"). So, I think I have to learn something along the way to proceed.

By the way, my computer skills: I just know a little of C (from an university course, absymal quality), I can handle Linux shell decently, I'm willing to learn.

My main question is:

**Is anyone willing to share his/her experience about open source rooting? Can someone point me some reference for learning about what's needed to understand the procedures that he/she has done to root his/her phone in an open source way?**

Or, if it is too broad:

**Does anyone with experience with superuser know where I can read something, more newbie friendly, to begin understanding how that procedure works?**

I thank you all for your attention.

¹No offense meant to the honest guys and gals that developed a closed source way to root! Unfortunately, closed source brings this kind of questions by nature.

Comment: Koush stopped development on Superuser a few years ago, it is not compatible with devices after KitKat. Look into SuperSU or Magisk. And what do you mean by "open source" methods? Just unlock the bootloader and flash recovery then SuperSU or Magisk... https://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-spirit/help/lg-spirit-h440n-thread-t3108435

Comment: Every up-to-date rooting method seems to be closed source, unfortunately. If you absolutely want open source, you'll better relinquish the LG's stock firmware and flash a custom ROM such as LineageOS (which provides root as a separate flashable addon) or one of its derivates. Personally, I'm not too fond of the new systemless root, be it SuperSU or Magisk, since, as I seemed to understand, it breaks old apps. **A last note of caution: stay away from any one-click-root. They are bundled with shady code and are prone to bricking devices.**

Comment: acejavelin, I suppose a full reflashing would remove everything that a malignous rooting app would add, but I'd also like to understand something along the way. By the way, Koush stopped development, but there is an active branch (last commit in the beginning of April) mantained by phhusson.

Death Mask Salesman, thanks for your advice. Looks like my intuition was good, and I sniffed "evil" on the one click root apps. Unfortunately, LineageOS does not support my phone specifically. Also, bootloader unlocking instructions on XDA developers tell me to "root the phone", and that's my problem.